# Does Zend_Validate work on filtered/unfiltered values?

Tags: zend-framework

i wonder if a `Zend_Form_Element` has filters attached to it, will `Zend_Validate` validate the filtered or unfiltered inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess it depends on what u pass as the values. in the context of forms,

```
$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()); // unfiltered
$form->isValid($form->getValues()); // filtered, cos getValues() returns filtered values
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfiltered.
Filters applied to the elements when you try to get their values via getValue() method.

Comment: so i guess u mean unfiltered if i use, what i see in most tuts, `$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams())` if i do something like `$form->isValid($form->getValues())` it will be filtered i guess?